# How can I type '≈' character in a Java String?

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, special-characters

I need to send a request to a RESTful Service which contains the '≈' special character.

The Request Body should look like this:

```
{
   "searchText":"Pipe ≈ 1,25d"
}
```

The '≈' symbol is not included in UTF-8 encoding.

In case you know how to pack this character in a Java String, please let me know.

Comment: is `U+2248` not working ? Actually Pardon me, It's just equerry  I didn't try.

Comment: "The '≈' symbol is not included in UTF-8 encoding." - What do you mean by that? Any Unicode character can be encoded in UTF-8. The UTF-8-encoded bytes are E2 89 88.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to type it depends on your keyboard and setup. You can, however, copy/paste strings into Java source.

```
String s = "Pipe ≈ 1,25d";
```